# Como armazenar contatos da agenda que criei em um vetor\matriz e lista-los? C

Tags: c, struct

Estou tentando desenvolver uma agenda em C.
Gostaria de saber como faço para armazenar contatos da agenda que criei em um vetor\matriz e lista-los?

Também estou quebrando a cabeça na hora de listar um número de telefone... (Segue print)

**PLUS**
Gostaria de dicas para aprimorar meu código e adicionar novas funcionalidades.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**PLUS**
Gostaria de dicas para aprimorar meu código e adicionar novas funcionalidades.

Segue o código:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct agenda {
    int cod;
    char nome[40];
    int tel;
    int vazio; // VAZIO = 0 e DISPONÍVEL = 1
} registros[100];

void cadastrar(int cod, int pos);
int verifica_pos();
int verifica_cod(int cod);
void consultar();
void excluir();
void zerar();

int main() {
    zerar();
    int op=0, retorno, codaux, posicao;
    while(op!=4){
        printf("************ AGENDA ************\n\n\n");
        printf(">>> MENU <<<\n\n");
        printf("1 - CADASTRAR\n");
        printf("2 - CONSULTAR\n");
        printf("3 - EXCLUIR\n");
        printf("4 - SAIR\n\n");
        printf("OPCAO: ");

        scanf("%d", &op);
        fflush(stdin);
        switch(op){
            case 1: {       //CADASTRAR
                posicao = verifica_pos();
                if (posicao != -1){
                printf("\nEntre com o codigo desejado: ");
                scanf("%d", &codaux);
                    fflush(stdin);
                    retorno=verifica_cod(codaux);
                    if(retorno==1)
                        cadastrar(codaux,posicao);
                    else
                        printf("\nCodigo ja existente!");
                }
                else
                    printf("\nA agenda esta cheia!");
            break;
            }

            case 2: {       //CONSULTAR
                consultar();
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                excluir();
                break;
            }
            case 4: {
                printf("\n\n TCHAU!!");
                break;
            }

    }
}
getch();
}

void cadastrar(int cod, int pos){
    pos = verifica_pos();
    registros[pos].cod = cod;
    printf("\nNOME: ");
    fgets(registros[pos].nome, 40, stdin);
    printf("\nTelefone: ");
    scanf("%d",&registros[pos].tel);
    registros[pos].vazio = 1;
    printf("\nCadastro Realizado com Sucesso!\n\n");    
}

int verifica_pos(){
        int cont=0;
        while(cont<=100){
            if(registros[cont].vazio==0)
            return(cont);
            cont++;
        }
    return(-1);
}

int verifica_cod(int cod){
    int cont=0;
    while(cont<=100){
        if(registros[cont].cod == cod)
        return(0);
        cont++;
    }
    return(1);
}

void consultar(){
    int cont=0, cod;
    printf("\nEntre com o codigo: ");
    scanf("%d", &cod);
    while(cont<=100){
        if(registros[cont].cod == cod){
            if(registros[cont].vazio == 1){
                printf("\nNome: %s", registros[cont].nome);
                printf("\nTelefone: %d\n\n", registros[cont].tel);
                break;
            }
        }
        cont++;
        if(cont>100)
            printf("\nCodigo nao encontrado!\n\n");
}
}

void excluir(){
    int cod, cont=0;
    printf("\nEntre com o codigo do registro que deseja excluir\n");
    scanf("%d",&cod);

    while(cont<=100){
        if(registros[cont].cod == cod)
            if(registros[cont].vazio == 1){
                registros[cont].vazio = 0;
                printf("\nExclusao realizada com sucesso!\n");
                break;
            }
            cont++;
            if(cont>100)
                printf("\nCodigo nao encontrado.\n");
    }
}

void zerar(){
    int cont;
    for(cont=0; cont<=100; cont++){
        registros[cont].vazio=0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui vão algumas dicas para seu código e eu dei alguns exemplos modificando o código original.

Dicas:

**1)** Tente não criar funções muito grandes. Quanto mais mais modularizado seu código ficar, será mais fácil para entender, mais fácil para testar, mais fácil para corrigir problemas.
Esta é uma boa prática de programação

Ex: A função `verifica_cadastro` foi criada para organizar melhor o código do `main()`, deixando-o menor e mais legível.

**2)** Em vários lugares o código está assim: `cont<=100`. O menor ou igual(`<=`) faz com que o código acesse desde a posição `0` até a `100` e isso está errado pois o array vai de `0` até `99`.
Para corrigir, basta substituir por `cont<100`

**3)** Não crie variáveis globais!!!
Esta é uma boa prática de programação.

Ex: sua lista de registros agora foi declarada na função `main()` e está sendo passada como argumento para as funções necessárias.

**4)** Use o `typedef` para definir um tipo para sua `struct`.
Esta é uma boa prática de programação.

Ex: a `struct` foi criada com o `typedef`, assim existira um tipo novo chamado `agenda`

**5)** A função `verifica_cod` verifica dentro de todos os elementos se o código ainda não existe. Porém os valores dos códigos não foram inicializados com `0`, portanto eles possuem lixo de memória e comparar seu código com lixo de memória pode causar erros.
Para corrigira basta adicionar a linha `registros[cont].cod=0;` dentro da função `zerar()`.

**6)** A linguagem c padrão não possui o tipo booleano (verdadeiro ou falso), então ela utiliza os valores `1` e `0` para isto.
Faça o teste:

```
printf("%d",(2>1)); // O resultado será 1 (verdadeiro)
printf("%d",(1>2)); // O resultado será 0 (falso)
```

Tente também passar um `int` para uma condição, ex:

```
if(0)
    printf("Imprimiu"); //O 0 é considerado falso, então não imprimirá nada
if(1)
    printf("Imprimiu"); //O 1 é considerado verdadeiro, então a mensagem será impressa
if(738)
    printf("Imprimiu"); //Qualquer outro valor também é considerado como verdadeiro
```

Então tente usar este padrão para funções que devem retornar se algo é verdadeiro ou falso.

Ex: A função `verifica_cod` diz se um código já existe, portanto possui um retorno com os valores `0` e `1`. Assim, você pode chamar a função direto no `if(verifica_cod(registros, cod))`.

**7)** O campo `vazio` de sua `struct` é desnecessário. Inicie todos os códigos com `0`, assim você corrige o problema número 5) e pode usar o campo de código para controlar se um registro existe ou não. Na hora de excluir um registro, basta definir seu `cod` como `0`.

Foram feitas mais correções e modificações no código, porém estão comentadas dentro do próprio código:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct agenda {
    int cod;
    char nome[40];
    int tel;
    //int vazio; // VAZIO = 0 e DISPONÍVEL = 1
}agenda;

void verifica_cadastro(agenda registros[]);
void cadastrar(agenda registros[], int cod, int pos);
int verifica_pos(agenda registros[]);
int verifica_cod(agenda registros[], int cod);
void consultar(agenda registros[]);
void excluir(agenda registros[]);
void zerar(agenda registros[]);

int main() {
    agenda registros[100];
    zerar(registros);
    int op=0;
    while(op!=4){
        printf("************ AGENDA ************\n\n\n");
        printf(">>> MENU <<<\n\n");
        printf("1 - CADASTRAR\n");
        printf("2 - CONSULTAR\n");
        printf("3 - EXCLUIR\n");
        printf("4 - SAIR\n\n");
        printf("OPCAO: ");

        scanf("%d", &op);
        fflush(stdin);
        switch(op){
            case 1: {       //CADASTRAR
                verifica_cadastro(registros);
                break;
            }

            case 2: {       //CONSULTAR
                consultar(registros);
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                excluir(registros);
                break;
            }
            case 4: {
                printf("\n\n TCHAU!!");
                break;
            }

    }
}
getch();
}

// Função que verifica se é possivel cadastrar
void verifica_cadastro(agenda registros[]){
    int codaux, posicao;
    posicao = verifica_pos(registros);
    if (posicao != -1){
        printf("\nEntre com o codigo desejado: ");
        scanf("%d", &codaux);
        fflush(stdin);

        if( verifica_cod(registros, codaux) )
            cadastrar(registros, codaux, posicao);
        else
            printf("\nCodigo ja existente!");
    }
    else
        printf("\nA agenda esta cheia!");
}

void cadastrar(agenda registros[], int cod, int pos){
    //pos = verifica_pos(registros); Linha duplicada, pos já veio com seu valor
    registros[pos].cod = cod;
    printf("\nNOME: ");
    fgets(registros[pos].nome, 40, stdin);
    printf("\nTelefone: ");
    scanf("%d",&registros[pos].tel);
    //registros[pos].vazio = 1;
    printf("\nCadastro Realizado com Sucesso!\n\n");
}

int verifica_pos(agenda registros[]){
        int cont=0;
        while(cont<100){
            if(registros[cont].cod==0)
                return(cont);
            cont++;
        }
    return(-1);
}

int verifica_cod(agenda registros[], int cod){
    int cont=0;
    while(cont<100){
        if(registros[cont].cod == cod)
        return(0);
        cont++;
    }
    return(1);
}

void consultar(agenda registros[]){
    int cont=0, cod;
    printf("\nEntre com o codigo: ");
    scanf("%d", &cod);
    while(cont<100){
        if(registros[cont].cod == cod){
            printf("\nNome: %s", registros[cont].nome);
            printf("\nTelefone: %d\n\n", registros[cont].tel);
            break;
        }
        cont++;
    }
    //O if pode ficar fora do while, pois será executado apenas uma vez
    if(cont==100)
        printf("\nCodigo nao encontrado!\n\n");
}

void excluir(agenda registros[]){
    int cod, cont=0;
    printf("\nEntre com o codigo do registro que deseja excluir\n");
    scanf("%d",&cod);

    while(cont<100){
        if(registros[cont].cod == cod){
            registros[cont].cod = 0; //O código também deve ser zerado
            //registros[cont].vazio = 0;
            printf("\nExclusao realizada com sucesso!\n");
            break;
        }
        cont++;
    }
    //O if pode ficar fora do while, pois será executado apenas uma vez
    if(cont==100)
        printf("\nCodigo nao encontrado.\n");
}

void zerar(agenda registros[]){
    int cont;
    for(cont=0; cont<100; cont++){
        registros[cont].cod=0;
        //registros[cont].vazio=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas, Lucas! Espero que aqui eu tenha a sorte de conhecer mais pessoas como você. :)

Answer (score -1):

Preciso de um menu para Cadastro de materiais de construção.
Com a possibilidade de cadastro [50];
Com o nome do sistema de "CONSTRUCAD".
Com as seguintes opções
1- Novo Cadastro
2- Lista
3- Consultar
4- Excluir
5- Desenvolvedores
6- Sair

Alguém me ajuda! por favor

Comment: Este é um campo de respostas. Para sanar sua dúvida aqui, veja como fazer perguntas. https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8089/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-sopt-vers%c3%a3o-curta

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```
registros[pos].cod = cod;
    printf("\nNOME: ");
   fgets(registros[pos].nome, 40, stdin);
```

-> como vai receber o nome sem o scanf ??